# Is my proof that $ B- \bigcup_{i=i}A_i \subseteq \bigcap_{i=I}(B - A_i)$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Suppose $x$ is arbitrary . Let  $$ x \in B- \bigcup_{i=i}A_i$$

Then $$ x \in B \land x \notin \bigcup_{i=i}A_i$$

So  $$ x \in B \land \forall i \in I \rightarrow x \notin A_i $$

Thus,

$$ x \in \bigcap_{i=I}(B - A_i)$$

Since $x$ is arbitrary,

$$B- \bigcup_{i=i}A_i \subseteq  \bigcap_{i=I}(B - A_i)$$

I'm not really sure about my conclusion since $ x \in \bigcap_{i=I}(B - A_i)$ seems to be equivalent to $ \forall i \in I \rightarrow x \notin A_i \land x  \in B  $ and not the third line of my proof. Or are they equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is perfectly fine. Good job! Concerning your question, maybe you should think about why $\forall i \in I \rightarrow x \notin A_i \land x  \in B$ is equivalent to the third line of your proof. That isn't very hard to see, since $x \in B$ doesn't depend on the $i$'s.

Comment: I'm confused as to how it's possible to add that $x \in B$ at the consequent of the conditional. They seem to belong in separate statements.

Comment: You can imagine the all quantor as up to infinitely many and-operations. Hence you just rearrange :)